# Cclassification of 1 vs infinite set

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

How to filter a specific type of image from the rest of the type of image.
Consider i have a data set consisting of images of dogs only. I need the classifier to differentiate between dogs and all the other types of images in the world that are not dogs.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you use pre trained deep learning models like vgg16, resnet50 which are available in Keras frame work. Train the model on images having only 2 category , i.e with dog and with out dogs. Than run the model on the existing dataset you will definately get your result.

Comment: Can you please elaborate "with out dogs"

Comment: For eg: there are 1000 images out of which 600 images consist of dogs and rest 400 images does not have dogs. Train the model with these 1000 images with labels of 600 as 'dogs' and rest 400 'no dogs'.Than your model is ready to differentiate between the images with dogs and without dogs.